# Найти точки на расстоянии от маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть задача вывести точки на N - расстоянии от заданного маршрута.

Изначально имеем выгрузку с каким-то числом точек, они могут находится по всему миру, нужно сделать выборку по этим точкам исходя построенного из маршрута.

[Пример](https://card4truck.ru/karta-azs)

**Вопрос:** что использовать для поиска нужных точек?

Comment: На вскидку видится, что вам потребуется сделать выборку всех точек маршрута, измерить расстояние между каждой точкой маршрута и каждой точной выгрузки и сравнить с N. Для измерения расстояний в API есть такой метод: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ICoordSystem-docpage/#method_detail__getDistance

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент подобных методов в API Яндекс.Карт не реализовано. Проверить можно только попадание точек в полигон. И на это в документации Яндекса есть [готовый пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones).

Однако преобразование линии в полигон для Яндекс.Карт само по себе является непростой задачей. Необходимо учесть огрубление окружностей на углах-поворотах, конечных точках маршрута, возможные пересечения линий и т.п. Проводить расчет на плоскости также будет неверным решением, поскольку геодезические линии между точками, а значит и углы в начальной и конечной точке участка маршрута могут сильно отличаться от результатов таких вычислений при значительных расстояниях.